# Java if+String dont work together

Tags: java

I'm learning java and I have a problem:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;


public class edytor{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
    Scanner czynowy = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Do you wanna editing existing file?");
    String tn = czynowy.nextLine() ;
    if(tn=="t")
{System.out.println("bleble"); }
    Scanner odpowiedz = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Type file name");
    String polozenie = odpowiedz.nextLine() ;
        System.out.println("################################");
      PrintWriter zapis = new PrintWriter(polozenie);
    Scanner tekst = new Scanner(System.in);
    String tekst1 = tekst.nextLine() ;
      zapis.println(tekst1);
      zapis.close();

  }
}
```

It's compiling, but
when in string tn I type t char this doesn't print "bleble". What should I do to make it work?
Greetings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (tn.equals("t") {...}
```

String is an object, and if you create 2 strings, even if they will have same value, they won't be equal to eachother

```
string1 == string2 // false
```

the `==` checks the object identity. while the `.equals()` method in String, checks the value.

The other way of doing this will be to use `for` loop, to loop through every `char` in each string, and check if it matches the character with the same place in another string.

or in your case, do this:

```
if (tn.getBytes()[0] == 't') {...}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
if (tn.equalsIgnoreCase("t") {
   ...
}
```

The reason you cannot compare two Strings with `==` is because Strings are objects. When you try to compare two objects directly, you are comparing their locations in memory. So, even if the **contents** of two Strings may be equal, their memory locations will not be equal.